# Mongoos, Callbacks, and Bears.. Oh My. Can't get to values:

Tags: javascript, express, callback, handlebars.js

Good day all,

I am convinced I'm tangled in callback nightmare trying to get simple values from a Mongoos.count passing a {query}.
I can get to the value and see it OK in console, from within the callback, but trying to get this out of an asyncronous callback setup is kicking my be-hive.

I'm using Node.js and Express trying to perform some seemingly simple tasks of getting a simple number count from my Model, 'Job'looking for the query above,

I have a similar scenario that is working in one instance of a router.get, and is able to write to a variable outside within the callback parents function. 
function like so:

```
router.get('/repairmanager', ensureAuthenticatedAdmin, function(req, res) {
    var list = [];  // This list populates ok even within the Job.find callback nest hole

    if(filter == 'userid' && query != "" || null){

        Job.find( {'userid' : new RegExp('^'+query+'$', "i")} )
          .then( function(doc){
            //console.log(doc);
            doc.forEach(function(job){
                list.push(job);    //<--- Populates just fine and can 
                                   //     see in res.render {{history}}
            });  
          }); 
          res.render('repairmanager', { history: { 'data' :list}} );
  }

)};
```

The above code works and is able to populate the list array...

BUT when I apply a similar scenario trying to get another value out of

```
function pendingCount(){

   var test = null;

   Job.count({'repairstatus': 'Pending Approval'}, function(err, cb){
       test = cb;
       console.log('test inside callback : ' + test);
   });
   console.log('test ourside callback :  ' + test);
   return test;
};
```

I cannot for the life of me get the test varable to populate what-so-ever nor get it to return to pendingCount() function,

I know there is a song and dance about asyn callback functions but.. but ..

Why is the list array able to be seen and written to in the other Mongoos function? and not in my other function trying to get a simple count of the query {"repairstatus": "Pending Approval"}  ?

Thanks for any educating feedback that helps to solve this.

Comment: OK I got my results but leaves me curious without an immediate answer ...   so when I change the var   test   to an empty array,  like   var test = [];   and then .push the the returning value to test[], it populates ok and i'm then able to get the value as I want externally outside of callback function. But why is a .push different than an = in an async under-world assignment? lol?  Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: The difference is that you are passing a reference to your array as opposed to passing `null`. This array gets populated **after** your function returns, which you should never trust as there is no guarantee of the timing that the array will be filled in. See my answer below for a more in-depth explanation of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example, it is not guaranteed that `list` will render correctly. If it is rendering correctly, it's by luck (`Job.find`'s promise and `res.render` are in a **race condition**, racing to reach `list`. `res.render` just happens to be winning in this case. This may not be the case given different network conditions, hardware conditions, or some other random reason).

If you wanted to be 100% sure that your `res.render` is called at the correct point in time *every* time, you'll need to take extra precautions.

In the first example, you'll want to move `res.render` into the `then` callback:

```
Job.find( {'userid' : new RegExp('^'+query+'$', "i")} ).then( function(doc){

    //console.log(doc);
    doc.forEach(function(job){
        list.push(job);    //<--- Populates just fine and can 
                           //     see in res.render {{history}}
    });  

    // render here
    res.render('repairmanager', { history: { 'data' :list}} ); 
});
```

For your second example, you won't be able to simply return `test`, since this value is filled asynchronously. What you'll have to do instead is return a `Promise` that will resolve to the desired value.

As of Mongoose >= 4.0, `count` will return a `Promise` by default, so you can just return the result of calling `count`:

```
function pendingCount(){
    return Job.count({'repairstatus': 'Pending Approval'});
};
```

To use `pendingCount`, you treat it like a `Promise`:

```
pendingCount().then(function(count) {
    console.log(count);
});
```

Making these changes will ensure you don't have any race conditions in your code, and everything will execute when you want it to, every time.

Comment: A comment on the first example:  I guess that explains why sometimes I load the .hbs page and my elements aren't loading. This happens seldomly but definitely noticeable, and can get it to show with a refresh/revisit.

Comment: I made the changes per your guidance and see a noticeable improvement on the loading of the page, and hopefully resolves the periodic  mis-loading of the incoming {{history}}.  thx!

The promise approach is returning a handful of ( [obj Obj] [obj Obj], false ) that I can't juice anything useful from. Perhaps im missing something .  I'm trying to obtain a count of how many elements in a db model that contain  "Pending Approval" in all the "repairstatus" keys, but hitting these hurdles.
Thank you @Christian for helping clarify my dewzies.

Comment: Are you extracting the value from the `Promise` by using `then` like in the last example I have above? Now that I think about it, you wouldn't have the `err` object passed to the `then` callback -- see my updated answer for extracting the count using `pendingCount().then()`

Comment: No luck with the Promise approach on 2nd example, but  I checked mongodb version is at 3.4 because I'm developing on a mac brew running mongod. 
I may need to migrate to another server that can do mongo v4.0, unless theres a backwards compatible approach that can be upgraded at another time

Comment: Which Node version are you using?

Comment: node -v is: v8.7.0 //
mongo --version is: MongoDB shell version v3.4.10

Comment: I don't know why I was having problems earlier, but I got it written using the Promise approach you suggested, and I am getting my value sent outside the .then function to the parent router.get function var. then I'm able to pass that to the res.render outgoing variables.
Fwew!